Can variables be stationary but not cointegrated?
This is possibly a naive question, but I have a linear regression with two independent variables and the time series of the individual variables have been tested and shown to be stationary.
However I made a plot that appeared to show the relationship between the two independent variables changing over time. This confused me a bit, since if they are stationary why would the relationship between them not also be stationary? Have I gone wrong with one of my tests? I think the answer may be that it is possible for this to happen, but I can’t put together an effective supporting argument.
I tested for stationarity between them by regressing them against each other and running the ADF test on the residuals.

Stationarity that you are examining via ADF tests and such concerns each series on their own but not their relationship. It is possible that each of the two time series is stationary on its own but that the relationship between them changes. E.g. consider two series where each one is i.i.d. Normal but the correlation between these sequences of Normal random variables varies over time $t$ following the rule $\rho_t=\sin(t)$. (See the R script below.) The relationship must only be constant if the two time series are jointly stationary (stationary as a vector time series).
Cointegration requires that time series are integrated to begin with, so there is no place for it if your time series are not integrated.

library(MASS)
T <- 100
rho <- sin(1:T)
x = y <- rep(NA, T)
for(t in 1:T){
  set.seed(1e6 + t) 
  z <- mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = c(0, 0), 
               Sigma = matrix(c(1, rho[t], rho[t], 1), nrow = 2))  
  x[t] <- z[1]
  y[t] <- z[2]
}
plot(x, type = "l", ylim = range(x, y), xlab = "time", ylab = "", 
     main = "x stationary, y stationary, but jointly nonstationary ")
lines(y, col = "blue")


